# Does it make sense for my filter to depend on the discrete sample variable n?

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, filter-design, digital-filters, filtering

I feel a little nervous asking this question as I am not sure if know what exactly I am trying to ask. But please see if you can help.

Ok, I have a filter whose output grows as long as the input is larger than a decay process:

$$
I(n)=\beta I(n-1,a)+q(P,t,n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1)
$$
Where $n$ is the discrete sample step, $q(P,t)$ is a function that transforms the current input for sample $n$ and $\beta$ is a problem specific parameter which is essentially similar to the $\alpha$ in the exponentially weighted moving average filter.

For simplicity I am going to presume the transformation of the input and write thus:
$$
I(n)=\beta I(n-1,a)+q(n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1)
$$

An interesting assumption is that when the input to the filter is stationary e.g. step input, the filter becomes:

$$
I(n)=(n\beta +1)q(n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1)
$$

This assumption is useful because it helps to eliminate $I(n-1,a)$ which we do not want to deal with since it is strange. So this 3rd equation is the equation I am working with and interested in; you can forget about the previous two as I have just used them for some context.

The diagram of this third filter is as shown:
[image: The block diagram of the 3rd filter]

(1) This 3rd filter works as expected but I need to be able to describe it. I have never worked with time-varying filters which I believe this filter is given the $n$ that multiplies $\beta$. Unless I am mistaken? If I try to get the transfer function, I get stuck at:

$$
I(z)-(1-\beta) I(z)z^{-1}= -\beta z\frac{dQ(z)}{dz}+Q(z)
$$
$$
I(z)[1-(1-\beta)z^{-1}] = ???
$$

I can't really get the $Q(z)$ out from the right hand side to form $H(z)= \frac{I(z)}{Q(z)}$. Am I doing it wrong or a transfer function is not possible here?

(2) The $n$ that multiplies $\beta$ in the 3rd equation only has a significant impact after a long period of time. For example dropping $n$ does not affect the impulse response, well clearly, and the step response seems to be affected only in amplitude; also the transfer function is then easily derived as:
$$
H(z)=\frac{\beta + 1}{1-(1-\beta)z^{-1}}
$$

This $H(z)$ agrees with data but I am struggling to find where such a filter that depends on the discrete sample time variable has been studied. I just want to see someone else dealing with such a filter so that I can see how it is treated or even if it makes sense as a traditional filter. So I am worried that I am doing something silly. So please tell me if you think this 3rd filter should not be called a digital filter and why? Also is it so bad that I dropped the $n$ because I could not get the transfer function of the 3rd filter.

Comment: What does $I(n,a)$ mean? What's $a$ ? Why does $I()$ sometimes has one argument and sometimes two.?

Comment: $I$ values were in different bins indexed by $a$ which are positive real numbers. Perhaps we can ignore it as later in the question I made an assumption that got rid of it such that indexing by $a$ is no more required.

Comment: If you drop $a$ from your first equation, it simply becomes $I(n) = I(n-1) + q(n)$. That's a really simple LTI f(if marginally stable)  filter with $I(n)$ as the output and $q(n)$ as the input. I can't follow how you derived your  third equation.  How does $n\beta$ end up as a multiplier for $q(n)$

Comment: Sorry about the confusion: I arrived at the 3rd equation using the following approximation: $I(n-1,a)$ $\approx$ $nq(n)$. This approximation works as long as the input signal $q(n)$ is stationary. The proof for it will not fit in here. So I did not just drop $a$ since that will lead to a different filter as you have shown.

Comment: So $I(n-1,a)$ is different from $I(n-1)$ ?

Comment: Yes they are not necessarily the same because $I(n-1)$ is the entire previous filter output while $I(n-1,a) $ is a fraction of $I(n-1)$.

Comment: I don't quite follow but you might delve into Laplace-Mellin xforms with kernel  
$t^{s-1)*e^{t\cdot w)$  
I have seen cases where superposition/delay was used when the signal strengths were being multiplied; a mistake.

Comment: @rrogers Could you please let me know what you did not understand as that will help me a lot. Essentially my main question is this: given the third equation(you may forget about how arrive at that equation), how can I get the transfer function? Is that not clear?

Comment: We might have to "get a room" due to hall monitors, but ....  What is Q(z)?  A free input?  
And why did you mix a discrete time description with a derivative?  Usually you should try you stay with one mode (but not always).  My interpretation is, your equation is actually LTI; but I sometimes misread (and vice-versa) and don't interpret things the way others do.  At present, I see the equation as an inhomogeneous (but linear) equation/system; with linear decay (say R-C circuit).  Driven by a fancy pre-filter that is driven by Q(z); i.e. a lead network.

Comment: My interpretation:  
$I(z)=(1-\beta)I\left(z\right)\cdot z^{-1}-\frac{b}{\triangle s}\cdot(Q\left(z\right)-Q\left(z\right)\cdot z^{-1})+Q(z)\cdot z^{-1}$  
Where $\triangle s$ is the real time between samples.  
Notice I moved the $z$ in $\frac{b}{\triangle s}\cdot z\cdot(Q\left(z\right)-Q\left(z\right)\cdot z^{-1})+Q(z)$   to  $ \frac{b}{\triangle s}\cdot(Q\left(z\right)-Q\left(z\right)\cdot z^{-1})+Q(z)\cdot z^{-1}$    
To preserve causality.  
I can draw the circuit or flow diagram if you need.

Comment: @rrogers $Q(z)$ is the z-transform of the input $q(n)$ .Is that what you are asking? This looks really interesting; How did you even manage to fit all  these equation in the comment. I need to now try to follow it to see if I can follow an write it out in Python code and test. I will feedback how I get on. Thanks

Comment: @rrogers The derivative appeared when I tried to z-transform the 3rd equation in my question. It is the z-transform of the signal $nq(n)$

Comment: @rrogers I am not sure I understand what you refer as free input  but $Q(z)$ is the z-transform of the input  $q(n)$ which are positive numbers in my application.

Comment: "free input: source unconstrained by the problem.   I suggest that you look at "works as expected" model with n*Q(n) (which I ignored on purpose); this is definitely not LTI (as was mentioned);  normally I would expect a system to behave the same if I run it now or after 5 years (of quiescence input) but you have a gain term that is being ratcheted up.  And I don't think you want to take a derivative with respect to "z"; it's an index term.  Not taken to be a signal in any sense; a consistent means of marking time (items in a sequence) that satisfies certain axioms/assumptions.

Comment: Perhaps the n in "n" is meant to be another input that modulates the Q(z) signal?  If I set the system back to the "big bang" I wouldn't expect to have a useful response now.  If it is a separate time signal starting at a particular value 0 at a particular time, then you do need more advance tools.  A block diagram would clarify things for me; with realizable blocks.  Your multiplication by z does violate causality in the normal mode of interpreting equations in casual coding/computers.  It can be done/have meaning, for retroactive analysis of data though.

Comment: @rrogers On free input, alright, the constraint is that $q(n)$ must be a statistically stationary signal as stated in my question, otherwise the system output will be inaccurate. Additionally but not a constraint, only positive values of $q(n)$ have physical meaning for my application. I feel like everyone is surprised about $nq(n)$ even though it is popular on z-transform tables. The time term $n$ in $nq(n)$ may not be thought of as an modulator since what it does is to make the system act as an accumulator.

Comment: @rrogers If your input to the system $$I(n)=(n\beta +1)q(n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1)$$ is stationary the response should not change after 5 years since the system will continue to accumulate its input constantly. It will be interesting if you could set the system back to the bang but just for fun argument sake, because the output of the filter goes to infinity ~$\beta$  times slower than $n$ (where $\beta <<<<< 1$) your hardware may ware out from processing infinite samples before the system output becomes an issue.

Comment: @rrogers To clarify, my system is: 
$$
I(n)=(n\beta +1)q(n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1)
$$ 
When I perform z-transform on my system to get its transfer function, I got:
$$
I(z)-(1-\beta) I(z)z^{-1}= -\beta z\frac{dQ(z)}{dz}+Q(z)
$$
using z-transform table. So I did not multiply by $z$, I only did z transform and the multiplication by $z$ showed up. You can try to do the z-transform of my time-domain system and you will see that the multiplication by $z$ is inherent. I am only comfortable of describing my system in the original time domain before the z-transform. So I will do a time domain diagram.

Comment: @rrogers I derived a transfer function using your interpretation as: $$H(z)=\frac{\frac{-\beta}{{\Delta}s}+(\frac{\beta}{{\Delta}s}+1)z^{-1}}{1-(1-\beta)z^{-1}}$$ assuming that you meant $\beta$ when you wrote $b$. The impulse response is: $$h(n)=\frac{(\beta^2+{\Delta}s)(1-\beta)^{n-1}}{{\Delta}s}$$ which interestingly describes my system response visually but I did not understand how you moved the $z$ around "to preserve causality"

Comment: Okay, I think I see where you have gone wrong (well maybe :) ), but I need the circuit/block diagram to avoid the "hall monitors" and answer.  As for your last equation in the question:"I am struggling to find where such a filter".  It's a simple IIR/RC filter that follows standard scaling rules with respect to  sample time.

Comment: @rrogers I have added the diagram to the question

Comment: Okay, where is the sampler?  In the abstract "n" has no meaning in the time domain.  Where is it fabricated?  Is n*b an input; it's certainly not a constant.   In other words, what is the first block with n*b;  adder, multiplier ?  Presently, I think of it as an autozero or 1/f model.  Or is the whole block a sampled data xfer diagram.

Comment: @rrogers $n$ is the sample step count. So in my Python implementation $n$ is an output of a sample counter. In my Simulink implementation I just used a counter block to output the current $n$. So in short,  the $n\beta$ is obtained by a multiplication between the output of a counter and the constant $\beta$.

Comment: Okay, since you have a simple ramp, you should model it as an integrator with constant input: $z^n=z^{(n-1)}+k\cdot \beta$ This puts the whole system into normal form.  You have a normal z transform system with IIR (infinite impulse response filter) and fed by a ramp.  Now the ramp isn't stable, so you will have a pole at 1 on the chart/equation which you could take out then put back in to evaluate response.

Comment: @rrogers Great. Not sure I see how to write this with my equations starting from time domain, but I will have a go and let you know. thanks a lot.

Comment: @rrogers I don’t think I understand $z^n=z^{n-1} + k\beta$. I am really struggling to see how to rewrite
$$I(n)=(n\beta +1)q(n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1) $$
to use your suggestion. Also I haven’t been able to rewrite it so that I can have $n$ as an integrator because it seems the equation will have two inputs (MISO system), i.e main input $q(n)$ and another input for the integrator? I don’t know how to formally write down the equations of a MISO system which I guess this has become...

Comment: @rrogers  ... So what I did was to replace $n$ with $m$ in my equation thus:
$$I(n)=(m\beta +1)q(n)+(1-\beta)I(n-1) $$
and explain in my paper that $m$ is an output of an integrator and just forget about the z-domain treatment for now. I have now used an integrator with 1 as a constant input for my practical implementation in Simulink and it makes much sense so thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transfer function is only defined for LTI systems. LTI means linear **time invariant**  Since your filter depends on time n, it is NOT time invariant. It's a **time variant** filter and hence it does not have a transfer function, impulse response or step response.

Mathematically analysis of time variant filters can be done, but it's a lot harder than for LTI filters. If the time variance is slow as comparted to the frequency range of interest, it can be approximated as piece-wise LTI systems.

I can't really tell what exactly your system does since I don't understand your notation (see comment).

Comment: Alright. I think your explanation is enough, but would you present an impulse response obtained from practically stimulating a time varying filter?

Comment: Regarding the notation, the filter was derived from operations that occurred in different bins. Say there are 3 bins $a=0,1,2$. If an input $x$ is judged to fall in the bin $a=0$, then the process will accumulate $x$ in the bin $a=0$ and at the same time will start emptying bins $a=1,2$ according to a decay rate $\beta$. The output of the process is the sum of the latest values in each bin. The filter I present is basically an approximation of this process. I did not include this detail as I thought it was not relevant.

Comment: An LTI impulse response is just a function of the time "lag", i.e. $h(\tau)$. A time variant impulse response, it's also a function of absolute time, so it becomes a function of two variables, i.e. $h(\tau,t)$